# Read excel data and loop through each line Java Apache POI

Tags: java

I have an Excel file and a Java model. I need to filter out data from the excel and fill the model based on it.

I am able to able to read the data from excel.

[image]

I need to create a model for example with the data from each line and fill:

```
public class Customer {
    
    int number;

    String CusotmerName;

    String CustomerLatest;
    
    String CustomerYear;
    
}
```

I can read from each cell using CellReference:

```
CellReference ref = new CellReference("A2");
Row r = sheet.getRow(ref.getRow());
        
Cell c = r.getCell(ref.getCol(), MissingCellPolicy.RETURN_BLANK_AS_NULL);
```

But i want a better method to iterate each line and map the info to the model. I havent found a solution close to this thereofre posting the question.
Thanks.

Comment: https://poi.apache.org/components/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#Iterator

Answer (score 1):

You can use foreach loop here and get the rows in sheet and then the cell in the rows and save the info in the model, you'll have to read each cell which can be accessed only by accessing sheet and then the cell so don't think you can optimize it further, although there might be something.

```
Sheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
for (Row row : sheet) {
 Customer c = new Customer(); 
 for (Cell cell : row) {
    c.CustomerName = cell.getStringCellValue();
```

Comment: We shouldn't use enhanced for loop for `Cell`s. It won't work here.

Comment: Will this give an error or won't read the values ?

Comment: Read your code a little bit... You're setting a single property with the string value of **every cell in the row**! To make matters worse, it doesn't even end up being the right cell, and if **any** of those cells are of different cells type from string, you will face issue

Comment: Didn't give an exact solution was just a rough idea on how we can, obviously cell values can be of different type, missed mentioning that part, thanks for pointing it out 

Answer (score 0):

OK, I'm going to have to fix this guy's answer...

Yes, you can use foreach loop to get the rows in the sheet...

However, I would add...

...that you should probably use a builder-like pattern.

Here is MVCE of the class, as well as a util method that may come in handy. I asked Phind AI to adapt it from my Groovy version (which is so much cleaner), so please take it with grain of salt...

### The `CustomerSheetReader`

```
public class CustomerSheetReader implements AutoCloseable {
    private Workbook spreadsheet;
    private Sheet sheet;
    // any other fields, e.g. input streams

    public CustomerSheetReader() {
        // open the workbook and initialize the sheet
    }

    public CustomerSheetReader(Sheet sheet) {
        this.sheet = sheet;
    }

    public List<Customer> read() { 
        List<Customer> customerModels = new ArrayList<CustomerSheet>();

        final int lastNonEmptyRowNum = SpreadsheetUtils.GetLastNonEmptyRowNum(this.sheet);
        for (int rowNum = 1; rowNum <= lastNonEmptyRowNum; rowNum++) { 
            customerModels.add(this.createModelFromRow(sheet.getRow(rowNum)));
        }

        return customerModels;
    }

    public Customer createModelFromRow(Row row) {
        Customer model = new Customer();

        for (int cellIdx = 0; cellIdx < row.getLastCellNum(); cellIdx++)
            model = this.buildModelFromCell(row.getCell(cellIdx), model);

        return model;
    }

    // TODO: we could make this better, by moving away from indices, and using dictionaries and/or callbacks instead. The latter would make the following code so much cleaner
    private Customer buildModelFromCell(Cell cell, Customer model) {
        switch (cell.getColumnIndex()) { 
            default:
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Cannot build model from cell having column index " + cell.getColumnIndex() + "!");

            case 0: 
                int id;
                if (cell.getType().equals(CellType.NUMERIC))
                    id = cell.getNumericCellValue();
                else 
                    id = Integer.parseInt(cell.getStringCellValue());

                model.number = id;
                return model;
            case 1:
                model.CustomerName = cell.getStringCellValue();
                return model;
            case 2: 
                model.CustomerLatest = cell.getStringCellValue();
                return model;
            case 3:
                // TODO: you may face issue with the string being of type numeric instead of type string. I leave handling of that up to you
                model.CustomerYear = cell.getStringCellValue();
                return model;

        }
    }

    @Override
    public void close() {
        // close the workbook and any input streams
    }
}
```

### The util method

In Groovy, I have this as one-liner thanks to its built-in callback-based `findLastIndexOf`. Here is Java version (DISCLAIMER: I have not tested this)

```
// SOURCE: https://www.phind.com/search?cache=s5oul8pz6nrmdz9lj49rh3o0
public class SpreadsheetUtils {
    public static int GetLastNonEmptyRowNum(Sheet sheet) {
        // Iterate over the rows from the end towards the beginning
        for (int i = sheet.getLastRowNum(); i >= 0; i--) {
            Row row = sheet.getRow(i);

            // If the row is null, continue to the next iteration
            if (row == null) {
                continue;
            }

            // Check if the row is non-empty
            if (row.getLastCellNum() != -1) {
                // Return the index of the non-empty row
                return i;
            }
        }

        // If no non-empty row is found, return -1
        return -1;
    }
}
```

### Thoughts

If you don't want to use the helper method, you can do what @Abhijeet has suggested: use for-each loop instead.